# How to modify fullcalendar columnFormat with bracket?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I need to display like this `10/15 (Sun)` as my client want ! But if I set that format on `columnFormat` ,it can't display within bracket text . How can I set `M/D (ddd)` to display in `columnFormat` . But you know , other like `{ddd}` is can display on week column

```js
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
        },
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        views : {
           agendaWeek : {
              columnFormat : "M/D (ddd)"
           }
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.6.1/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.6.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Comment: Can you make plunker of this code snippet and share the link?

Comment: I did one on code snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I have been researching nearly 9 hour , I got easy solution one if I put `[]` on each bracket !!! :)

```
columnFormat : "M/D [(]ddd[)]"   //added => []
//                  ^ ^   ^ ^
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can add bracket around day but I hope below will work for you :

```js
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
        },
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        views : {
           agendaWeek : {
              month: 'dddd',    // Sun, Mon,Tue etc
            week: 'dddd, MMM dS', // Fri 10/20
            day: 'dddd, MMM dS'  // Friday 10/20
           }
        }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.6.1/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.6.1/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Comment: I want `10/15 (Sun)` instead of `Sun 10/15` and my problem is if I put `(` it can't display

Comment: @DavidJorHpan, `(` is not allowed in format which means you can not add `()` around day.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. `columnFormat : "M/D ddd"`

When I  tried brackets like this `(ddd)` it didn't work.

Comment: I saw it, tried it and saw it worked. But why () brackets didn't let days value to be written? Why we should use [] (square brackets) to write brackets?

Comment: Btw, thanks for Q&A. It really beatified my application :)

Comment: I didn't know the main reason why `()` is not letting ? May be using in their format changing ??

Comment: I poked around /fullcalendar.js file and found where columnFormat value was changed. 

When fullcalendar tries to return column titles, it uses its `date.format()` function. And this function doesn't format brackets properly, it seems. But I couldn't found what `format()` function fullcalendar was using.

I tried using  `moment(date).format(("ddd"))` end it formatted my date value properly.